# Connecting points with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, logic, circuits

I'm trying to connect an input to one of the gates in a logic diagram using the circuitikz package.

[image]

I've got this far with various sources (inc. SE) but would like to connect the first dot on the B input to the and2 gate input 2.  ANd ... then add the crossing through the C input.

I suspect I'm missing something quite simple ....

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{
        logic ports=ieee,
        logic ports/scale=1,
        logic ports/fill=white
    }

    \draw
    (0,2)       node (and1) [xshift=1cm,and port]      {and1}
    (and1.out)  node        [anchor=south]        {\it A.B}
    (and1.in 1) node (A1)   [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]  {A}
    (and1.in 2) node (B1)   [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]  {B} 
    
    (0,0)       node (or1)  [xshift=1cm,or port]       {or1}
    (or1.out)   node        [anchor=south]         {\it B+C}
    (or1.in 2)  node (C1)   [anchor=east, xshift=-1cm] {C}
    (0,-2)       node (and2) [xshift=1cm,and port]       {and2}
    (and2.out)  node        [anchor=south]              {\it B.C}
    (4,-1)       node (and3) [and port] {and3}
    (and3.out)  node        [anchor=north,xshift=0.5cm] {\it BC(B+C)}
    (7,1)       node (or2) [or port] {or2}
    (or2.out)   node (Q)    [anchor=west] {Q = AB+BC(B+C)}
    
    (A1) -- (and1.in 1)
    (B1) -- (and1.in 2)
    (C1) -- (or1.in 2)
    (B1) -| (or1.in 1)
    (C1) -| (and2.in 1)
    (B1) -- (and2.in 2)
    
    (and1.out) -| (or2.in 1)
    (or1.out) -| (and3.in 1)
    (and2.out) -| (and3.in 2)
    (and3.out) -| (or2.in 2)
    ;  

    \node [xshift=1.25cm] at (B1) {$\bullet$};
    \node [xshift=1.25cm] at (C1) {$\bullet$};
    \node [xshift=0.7cm] at (B1) {$\bullet$};
    
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to avoid the crossing --- the standard when drawing circuits says that in absence of a dot, crossing wires do not connect, so it's good to teach and learn the standard. In that case, it's easy:

1. do not draw directly from `(B1)` to `(and2.in 2)`, that's the diagonal line you have;
2. use the `circ` node for the connections (better than a bullet), and name the interesting one;
3. use orthogonal coordinates. See:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \ctikzset{
        logic ports=ieee,
        logic ports/scale=1,
        logic ports/fill=white
    }

    \draw
    (0,2)       node (and1) [xshift=1cm,and port]      {and1}
    (and1.out)  node        [anchor=south]        {\it A.B}
    (and1.in 1) node (A1)   [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]  {A}
    (and1.in 2) node (B1)   [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]  {B}

    (0,0)       node (or1)  [xshift=1cm,or port]       {or1}
    (or1.out)   node        [anchor=south]         {\it B+C}
    (or1.in 2)  node (C1)   [anchor=east, xshift=-1cm] {C}
    (0,-2)       node (and2) [xshift=1cm,and port]       {and2}
    (and2.out)  node        [anchor=south]              {\it B.C}
    (4,-1)       node (and3) [and port] {and3}
    (and3.out)  node        [anchor=north,xshift=0.5cm] {\it BC(B+C)}
    (7,1)       node (or2) [or port] {or2}
    (or2.out)   node (Q)    [anchor=west] {Q = AB+BC(B+C)}

    (A1) -- (and1.in 1)
    (B1) -- (and1.in 2)
    (C1) -- (or1.in 2)
    (B1) -| (or1.in 1)
    (C1) -| (and2.in 1)
    % (B1) -- (and2.in 2) <<<- removed

    (and1.out) -| (or2.in 1)
    (or1.out) -| (and3.in 1)
    (and2.out) -| (and3.in 2)
    (and3.out) -| (or2.in 2)
    ;

    \node [circ, xshift=1.25cm] at (B1) {};
    \node [circ, xshift=1.25cm] at (C1) {};
    \node [circ, xshift=0.7cm](B1-dot1) at (B1) {};
    
    \draw (B1-dot1) |- (and2.in 2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on the crossing, you can do this instead of the last draw:

```latex
    % find the crossing between wire C and the vertical of B1-dot
    \coordinate (c cross) at (B1-dot1 |- C1);
    % plant a jump crossing node there (vertical)
    \node [jump crossing, rotate=90](X) at (c cross) {};
    % draw the connections, be careful with the rotated anchors 
    \draw (B1-dot1) -- (X.east) (X.west) |- (and2.in 2);
```

to obtain:

[image]

Notice that this is suboptimal, you should also remove the wire from `C1` to `or1.in 2` and substitute it with two segments around the crossing `X`, but I'll let this to you ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I replaced your bullets with circs and moved them into the lines where they are used.  You can also add connections using `to[short,*-*]` but only in straight lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{
        logic ports=ieee,
        logic ports/scale=1,
        logic ports/fill=white
    }

    \draw
    (0,2)       node (and1) [xshift=1cm,and port]      {and1}
    (and1.out)  node        [anchor=south]        {\it A.B}
    (and1.in 1) node (A1)   [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]  {A}
    (and1.in 2) node (B1)   [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]  {B} 
    
    (0,0)       node (or1)  [xshift=1cm,or port]       {or1}
    (or1.out)   node        [anchor=south]         {\it B+C}
    (or1.in 2)  node (C1)   [anchor=east, xshift=-1cm] {C}
    (0,-2)       node (and2) [xshift=1cm,and port]       {and2}
    (and2.out)  node        [anchor=south]              {\it B.C}
    (4,-1)       node (and3) [and port] {and3}
    (and3.out)  node        [anchor=north,xshift=0.5cm] {\it BC(B+C)}
    (7,1)       node (or2) [or port] {or2}
    (or2.out)   node (Q)    [anchor=west] {Q = AB+BC(B+C)}
  
    (A1) -- (and1.in 1)
    (B1) -- (and1.in 2)
    (C1) -- (or1.in 2)
    (B1) -| (or1.in 1) node[circ, midway] {}
    (C1) -| (and2.in 1) node[circ, midway] {}
    (B1) ++(0.7cm,0) node[circ] {} |- (and2.in 2)
    
    (and1.out) -| (or2.in 1)
    (or1.out) -| (and3.in 1)
    (and2.out) -| (and3.in 2)
    (and3.out) -| (or2.in 2)
    ;  
    
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```